# Reference a input box id on kivy screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I think this problem is easy to solve, but i dont have experience enough to do this.
So, I want to reference the input text (MDTextField on kv file) for the variable "name" that is inside the press() function, so that I can write inside the popup.
I'm learning kivymd for a college project, so, discount the errors and unnecessary informations :/

**Here is my kv file**

```
Screen:
    id: screen1
    NavigationLayout:
        id: navigation
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                id: fact
                name: 'fact'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Menu"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                    Widget:
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Fact Checker"
                    font_size: 56
                    font_name: "MontserratBold"
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.75, 'center_y': 0.7}
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: (53/255, 183/255, 1, 1)

                MDTextField:
                    id: input_box
                    hint_text: "Type here"
                    font_size: 18
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.45}
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 500
                    multiline: True
                    helper_text: "Type the title of the news"
                    helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: (53/255, 183/255, 1, 1)
                    line_color_normal: 1, 1, 1, 1

                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: "Check"
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.25}
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    on_press: app.press()

                MDLabel:
                    markup: True
                    text: "<Developed by: [color=#cfd0d1]Caio Barreto and Gabriel Queiroz[/color]>"
                    font_name: "Montserrat"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: (53/255, 183/255, 1, 0.5)
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.74, 'center_y': 0.1}
            Screen:
                name: 'discord'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Menu"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                    Widget:
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'teste1'

            Screen:
                name: 'add'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Menu"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
                    Widget:
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'teste2'

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                ScrollView:
                    DrawerList:
                        id: md_list

                        MDList:
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Menu"
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = "fact"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "home"

                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Discord"
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = "discord"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "discord"


                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: "Add more news"
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = "add"
                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: "circle-edit-outline"
```

**Here is my python code:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton, MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import NavigationLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from helper import username_input
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen

LabelBase.register(name="MontserratBold", fn_regular="font/Montserrat-Bold.ttf")
LabelBase.register(name="Montserrat", fn_regular="font/Montserrat-Medium.ttf")

class FactCheckerApp(MDApp):

    class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
        pass

    def build(self):
        self.file = Builder.load_file('projeto.kv')
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightBlue"
        print(self.file.Screen.ids.)
        return self.file

    def press(self):
        name = self.screen1.navigation.screen_manager.fact.input_box.text
        close_button = MDFlatButton(text='Close', on_release=self.close_dialog)
        self.dialog = MDDialog(title='Answer', text=name, size_hint=(0.5, 1), buttons=[close_button])
        self.dialog.open()

    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactCheckerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the `MDTextField`, you can just reference it through its `id`, which is defined in the widget that is the root of the `kv` rule where the `id` is defined (in this case, in the `Screen`). Try changing:

```
    name = self.screen1.navigation.screen_manager.fact.input_box.text
```

to:

```
    name = self.root.ids.input_box.text
```

in the `press()` method.

Comment: it doesnt worked, the program closes before it appears on the screen
and the error that appeared at the end of the code is:

   File "D:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 616, in parse_level
     current_object.children = _objects
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'

Comment: That message suggests that there may be an error in your `kv` file.

Comment: I don't get any error from the `kv` that you posted here, so start by commenting out changes until you eliminate the error message.